# 2d Graphics advantages & disadvantages over 2d Images in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, 2d, graphic

I need to know whether there is any advantages or disadvantages on using 2d graphics in wpf over 2d images or not?

I mean if I'm going to display an ellipse in a wpf window which one is more useful and why? To create an Ellipse object or to create an Image control and then load an pre-designed ellipse image into it?

Does using 2D graphics have any advantages in the sense that they consume less memory or increase performance or anything like that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to read the [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373.aspx) article on MSDN and pay special attention to the *Vector Graphics* and *About Resolution and Device-Independent Graphics* sections. That should give you an idea of the advantages of vector graphics.

Answer (score 2):

An Image is not realy good scalable.

An vector Graphics is.

On a high dpi display your Image with Width = 300 (Units not pixels) and Height = 300 (units) is on a Display with 96 dpi not bigger than a Display with 144dpi. But the Image on the 144 dpi display needs more Pixels for the same size.

1 Unit is 1/96 inch.

So it is better to have a scalable "image" than a fixed one.

Its one of the features of wpf that winform don't have! and the reason why you should not use Pixels as a Size / Width / Height / Position / etc.

**Excursus:**

In winform it is hard to programm a scalable programm. on high dpi monitors the font, buttons etc. looks very small. there was no option to solve this problem.
so windows programmed an algorithm that creates a bitmap of the programm and scales this up.
So: the progamms width and height is the same as before, but the user sees a much bigger one (the Bitmap). The user input is then recalculated on the real sized application; Everything is working fine - and looking fine.

Hope that helps and is correct.

Comment: thank you. so is it all about scalability and it doesn't have anything to do with performance or memory?

Comment: uhm i am not sure. but this is one aspect i think. there may be some other like memory and performance.

Comment: and i also think that a GUI don't need a good performance. the user is much slower than the computer. but the user sees when the grafic / GUI looks bad